# Why SOAP does not throw exception with invalid datetime value?

Tags: datetime, soap, null

I have got one input parameter defined on the xsd as:

```
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Using SoapUI, I'm sending an invalid date time as:

```
<value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">NOT_VALID_DATETIME</value>
```

And the webservice is receiving null value, instead of throwing an exception.

What can I do to force an exception when a non valid datetime is received?